Problem in outputting bibliography with natbib
I want to use this template of a journal
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 

\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{natbib}




\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}


\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

%%==================================%%
%% Sample for unstructured abstract %%
%%==================================%%

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}

%%================================%%
%% Sample for structured abstract %%

\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}



\maketitle

\cite{bib1}

\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file
%% if required, the content of .bbl file can be included here once bbl is generated
%%\input sn-article.bbl


\end{document}

The file name is sn-bibliography contains the code
@article{bib1,
  author        = "Campbell, S. L. and Gear, C. W.",
  title         = "The index of general nonlinear {D}{A}{E}{S}",
  journal       = "Numer. {M}ath.",
  volume        = "72",
  number        = "2",
  pages         = "173--196",
  year          = "1995"
}

When I compile, Latex outputs this image without bibligraphy. So how to solve problem so that Latex outputs the bibliography


what do you mean by "But when I compile by biblatex " ? biblatex is not involved here you need pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex twice more

I don't see any indication in your code of the biblatex citation management  package being employed. Instead, the code does employ the natbib citation management package, along with the sn-mathphys-num bibliography style. Please clarify.

Off-topic: (a) The amsfonts package is loaded automatically by the amsymb package. No need to load amsfonts a second time. (b) Why do you write {D}{A}{E}{S} in the title field of the bibliographic entry? {DAES} works just as well.

@DavidCarlisle  I want to output the bibliography

@Mico In biblatex, we compile the code firstly by biblatex and two times PDFlatex, so for natbib how to do this to outputting bibliography

You write as if biblatex is an external program that needs to be run. That is definitely wrong. The external program you seem to be thinking of is called bibtex. Have you been running bibtex? Your screenshot suggests that this is not the case.

Yes you want to output a bibliography but that is not what I asked. What commands did you use you said But when I compile by biblatex but there is no biblatex command (it is a latex package) and you are not using that package. The output you show [?] is expected if you have not run bibtex. Have you run bibtex?

@DavidCarlisle, yes I have compile with biblatex and the result is [?]

You are not reading any of the comments people are making. You can not compile with biblatex there is no such command. What commands did you use, and in what order?

@DavidCarlisle, I don't know how to use natbib, the journal forces to use natbib, my question how to get the bibliography by natbib package ???

why can you not answer the questions asked? what commands have you used. You need to run pdflatex, then bibtex, then pdflatex then pdflatex. There is no command called biblatex
